# Closing tcp connection take FIVE steps while I have learnt that only FOUR steps are needed

Tags: tcp, connection, netty, tcpdump

the sequence below is captured by tcpdump on the loopback interface !

- 15:16:14.958221 IP6 ::1.55576 > ::1.8007: Flags [F.], seq 152, ack 153, win 12740, options [nop,nop,TS val 1112109047 ecr 1112109047], length 0
- 15:16:14.958246 IP6 ::1.8007 > ::1.55576: Flags [.], ack 153, win 12739, options [nop,nop,TS val 1112109047 ecr 1112109047], length 0
- 15:16:14.958255 IP6 ::1.55576 > ::1.8007: Flags [.], ack 153, win 12740, options [nop,nop,TS val 1112109047 ecr 1112109047], length 0
- 15:16:14.958618 IP6 ::1.8007 > ::1.55576: Flags [F.], seq 153, ack 153, win 12739, options [nop,nop,TS val 1112109047 ecr 1112109047], length 0
- 15:16:14.958727 IP6 ::1.55576 > ::1.8007: Flags [.], ack 154, win 12740, options [nop,nop,TS val 1112109047 ecr 1112109047], length 0

note

- port 55576 is the client while port 8007 is the server.
- The server is an echo server which writes back everything received!
- I am using telnet from OS X terminal!
- the server is written by netty running on the jvm!

I am wondering why we need the third step ?

Comment: One of the ACKS is to acknowledge prior data. It isn't part of the close handshake. The RFCs do not lie.

Comment: I have re-checked the whole complete packet sequence, I don't think you are right!  since the first ACK has acknowledged the packet with number of 153, which means it has received the packet 153, how come the tcp send another ACK to acknowledge prior data? It doesn't make any sense since tcp uses cumulative acknowledgement !

Comment: @EJP The first FIN packet with ACK number 153 which meas the packet before 153 have been received !   There is no need to send another ACK to acknowledge packet 153 !